# How to mock an angular subscription in Jasmine/Karma

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm having difficulty working out how test a component that is using a service.

My service:

```
export class AgentService {
  private dataCollectorsObervable: Observable<Agent[]> = null;
  private meterOperatorsObervable: Observable<Agent[]> = null;
  private suppliersObervable: Observable<Agent[]> = null;

  private dataCollectorIdSource = new Subject<number>();
  private meterOperatorIdSource = new Subject<number>();

  dataCollectorIdAnnounced$ = this.dataCollectorIdSource.asObservable();
  meterOperatorIdAnnounced$ = this.meterOperatorIdSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  }

  announceDataCollectorId(dataCollectorId: number) {
    this.dataCollectorIdSource.next(dataCollectorId);
  }

  announceMeterOperatorId(meterOperatorId: number) {
    this.meterOperatorIdSource.next(meterOperatorId);
  }
.......
```

Then in my parent components constructor I subscribe to the service:

```
agentService.dataCollectorIdAnnounced$.subscribe();
agentService.meterOperatorIdAnnounced$.subscribe();
```

further down in my code I use the service:

```
if (isValid) {
        this.getMpanAgentsSubscription = this.agentService.getMpanAgents(this.request.mpan).subscribe((mpanAgents) => {

          if (mpanAgents !== null) {
            this.agentService.announceDataCollectorId(mpanAgents.dataCollectorId);
            this.agentService.announceMeterOperatorId(mpanAgents.meterOperatorId);
            this.getMpanAgentsSubscription = null;
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.agentService.announceDataCollectorId(null);
        this.agentService.announceMeterOperatorId(null);
      }
```

my child component also subscribes to the service and also populated some dropdowns on initialisation :

```
 public dataCollectors: SelectItem[] = [];
  public meterOperators: SelectItem[] = [];
  public dataCollectorSubscription: Subscription;
  public meterOperatorSubscription: Subscription;

  public showMe: boolean = true;

  @Input() public request = null;

  constructor(protected route: ActivatedRoute, private agentService: AgentService) {
    this.dataCollectorSubscription = agentService.dataCollectorIdAnnounced$.subscribe(dataCollectorId => {
      this.request.dataCollectorId = dataCollectorId;
    });

    this.meterOperatorSubscription = agentService.meterOperatorIdAnnounced$.subscribe(meterOperatorId => {
      this.request.meterOperatorId = meterOperatorId;
    });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const agents: AgentLists = this.route.snapshot.data['agents'];

    this.dataCollectors.push({ label: '', value: null });
    for (const agent of agents.dataCollectors) {
      this.dataCollectors.push({ label: agent.name, value: agent.id });
    }

    this.meterOperators.push({ label: '', value: null });
    for (const agent of agents.meterOperators) {
      this.meterOperators.push({ label: agent.name, value: agent.id });
    }
  }
```

originally all the code in the child component was in the parent. I've componentised this part because we use it in several places. The code works fine, but moving out the code from the parent has broken all our tests.

the stub in my spec file for agentservice.getMpanAgents is:

```
agentServiceStub = {
        getMpanAgents(mpan: string): Observable<MpanAgents> {
          if (mpan === mpanValidWithDetails) {
            return new BehaviorSubject<MpanAgents>(new MpanAgents());
          } else {
            return new BehaviorSubject<MpanAgents>(null);
          }
        }
```

im struggling to change this to meet the new structure of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider usage of [ng-mocks](http://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks)

It has [MockInstance](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks#mockinstance) and [ngMocks.defaultMock](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks#ngmocksdefaultmock)

The dependencies might be mocked with fake observables:

```js
const fakeStream$ = new Subject();
const fakeData$ = new Subject(); // Or EMPTY if you don't need it in test.
const fakeMeter$ = new Subject();

beforeAll(() => MockInstance(AgentService, () => ({
  getMpanAgents: () => fakeStream$,
  dataCollectorIdAnnounced$: fakeData$,
  meterOperatorIdAnnounced$: fakeMeter$,
})));

afterAll(MockReset);

beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(ComponentToTest)
  .mock(ChildComponent)
  .mock(AgentService));

it('test', () => {
  const fixture = MockRender(ComponentToTest);
  fakeStream$.next('someVlue');
  fakeMeter$.next('anotherValue');
  // ....
});
```